# Opening a PDF file in Acrobat Reader

Tags: android, acrobat, javafxports

In my application I'd like to show a help file (PDF) to the user. The help file is published as asset and on first request copied to the external storage.
**Adobe Acrobat Reader starts but does not show the file**.

What am I missing ?

I use platform package 21 and Acrobat Reader 20.1.1 on Android 9.1.

**Note**: Via the file viewer I can see the file and on touching Adobe Acrobat Reader opens with the file.
Adobe Acrobat Reader is set as default application with option "Always".

Here is the code:

```
public static void open(Activity activity)
{
    // copy help file to external storage
    String filename = "helpfile.pdf";
    File pubFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/"+filename);
    if(!pubFile.exists())
    {
        InputStream ims = null;
        try {
            ims = activity.getAssets().open(filename);
            Files.copy(ims, pubFile.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(ims != null)
            {
                try {
                    ims.close();
                    pubFile.delete();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to copy help file to accessible folder.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    return;
                }
            }
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(activity, "Failed to copy help file to accessible folder.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            return;
        }
    }

    // open the help file with application for PDF files (Adobe Acrobat)
    if(pubFile.exists() && pubFile.canRead())
    {
        // EDIT Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.fromFile(pubFile));
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity
                        , "com.myapp.fileprovider"
                        , pubFile)); // EDIT
        intent.setType("application/pdf");
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);

        PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
        if (activities.size() > 0) {
            activity.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(activity, "No application to show help file.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is what I did due to the recommendation of CommonsWare

1. Replaced Uri.fromFile(...) with FileProvider.getUriForFile(...) (see code above)
2. AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.myapp" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
    </provider>
</manifest>
```

3. src\android\res\xml\file_paths.xml:

```xml
<paths>
    <external-path name="external" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: You should be crashing with a `FileUriExposedException`. Use `FileProvider` and its `getUriForFile()` method, not `Uri.fromFile()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I changed my code as you recommended and added the xml configs I thought to be correct (see EDIT in my post), but the result is still the same.